# Regex for up to and including three words

Tags: regex

I have been looking for some Regex for a Sonarqube query. There is a lot out there but I have not been able to find this:
The regex needs to find: Up to and including three words with any number of spaces before, between or after the one, two or three words.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What language. maybe regex is not needed. And an example would be nice too

Answer (score 0):

Allows for optional spaces before words and optional words between 1 and 3 (inclusive) times

```
(((\s+)?(\w+)){1,3}\s*?)\n
```